# Using EvaluateScriptAsync to call javascript in CefSharp

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio-2013, cefsharp

Currently using CefSharp in my Visual Studio project to show a web browser. I'm using the EvaluateScriptAsync to call a function in my javascript.

But I encounter a small problem.

The below can work:

```
    string strMsg = "12345";
    var script = string.Format("testing({0});", strMsg);
    browser.EvaluateScriptAsync(script);
```

The below cannot work:

```
    string strMsg = "ABCDE";
    var script = string.Format("testing({0});", strMsg);
    browser.EvaluateScriptAsync(script);
```

Then on the html side:

```
  testing = function (error) {
      alert(error);
      return false;
  };
```

Why is it I can't send alphabets string?

Is there a difference between sending a numbers and sending alphabets?

Comment: Run `testing(ABCDE);` in the browser's command line and see what happens. Your conclusion?

Answer (score 1):

The string you generate will execute as JavaScript. As it stands in your second example when the code executes it would be looking for a variable named `ABCDE`. You need to encapsulate in quotes to make it into a string.

```
string strMsg = "ABCDE";
```

should be

```
string strMsg = "`ABCDE`";
```

or

```
string strMsg = "\"ABCDE\"";
```

For debugging, `CefSharp` supports `DevTools` which you can open and see JavaScript console output.

Comment: I dont want to hardcode the strMsg. Then if I use string.Format, I write like this: string.Format("testing('{0}');", strMsg); Is it correct?

Comment: What is the output of `script`?

Comment: Make sure you use single quotes. Use the other syntax if required.

Comment: Is there any string character limit? My string is quite long for my strMsg

Comment: Theoretically the limit should be in the megabytes, I've never attempted to find it's max. If you don't need to return a value then considering using `ExecuteScriptAsync`

Comment: I think my strMsg must have some "" or '' character in it. That's why can't send through.